# Why does systemd display certain service units that do not have an associated unit-file?

Tags: debian, systemd, systemctl, systemd-unit

I have been reading up and investigating systemd and systemctl on Debian 8 Jessie.

When running

```
$ sudo systemctl list-units --all --type=service
```

a few services appear in the list that have no unit-file associated to them such as:

> ```
> ● clamav-daemon.service | not-found | inactive | dead | clamav-daemon.service
>
> ● console-screen.service | not-found | inactive | dead | console-screen.service
>
> ● festival.service | not-found | inactive | dead | festival.service
>
> ● greylist.service | not-found | inactive | dead | greylist.service
>
> ● keymap.service | not-found | inactive | dead | keymap.service
>
> ● krb5-kdc.service | not-found | inactive | dead | krb5-kdc.service
> ```

Yet at the same time, when running

```
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files --all --type=service
```

there are no unit-files associated to the above units.

My question is:

How can systemctl list these services as units (or even know that these units exist), if there are no unit-files that exist for these units?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/836992/229499

Comment: @muru thats it after doing a little probing with grep I found that all these services were listed in SysVinit scripts in /etc/init.d. Being backwards compatible,  systemd also initialises the scripts located in this folder. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Some unit "files" are created on the fly (for example for devices, their entries are also created by the kernel as the devices get initialized), and only ever exist in memory.